# Accept credit cards without PayPal creating account not working

Tags: paypal, credit-card

Currently my host has this script and it does not work in accepting credit cards without creating a PayPal account. Any help to point out some reason why?

```
private function RedirectToPayPal($token)
{
$payPalURL = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=' .   urlencode($token);
header("Location: ".$payPalURL);
exit;
}

$requestParams = array(
   'RETURNURL' => site_url().'/payment/paypal/success_deposit/'.$order_id,
   'CANCELURL' => site_url().'/payment/paypal/cancelled_deposit/'.$order_id,
   'SOLUTIONTYPE' => 'Sole',
   'LANDINGPAGE' => 'Billing'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the correct variables, but keep in mind that not every account has the ability to offer their customers the ability to pay with a credit card without creating a PayPal account.  I would have to look at the account you are using specifically.  Can you provide me with the email address for the seller account, or the correlation ID of the API call, or the EC Token to locate the account information in our logs.  Also, mention if this is for sandbox or live.

Comment: Hi, Please visit my website where I have it setup. You can make a test order at http://www.imobileunlock.com/en/tools/solution/iphone-network-finder. Just input these info for IMEI: 012345678901234, Name: Bob Doe, and email: bobdoe@fake.com then press Make Request button to get transfer to PayPal checkout.

Comment: Are you passing over the SOLUTIONTYPE and LANDINGPAGE variables over in your EC call.  When I check the logs, I do not see these variables getting passed over in your SetExpressCheckout API call.  Please reconfirm that you are passing these variables over.  If you can provide the string minus the API credentials that you are sending over this would be helpful as well.

Comment: I'm trying to get the info you need from my developer. I will post here soon. Thank you.

Comment: This is what they gave me:  $requestParams = array(
           'RETURNURL' => site_url().'/payment/paypal/success_deposit/'.$order_id,
           'CANCELURL' => site_url().'/payment/paypal/cancelled_deposit/'.$order_id,
           'SOLUTIONTYPE' => 'Sole',
           'LANDINGPAGE' => 'Billing'

        );
.....
$response = $this->request('SetExpressCheckout', $requestParams + $orderParams + $items);

Comment: For some reason, your site is not passing over these variables.  I walked through your checkout and they are not being sent over to PayPal.  The SOLUTIONTYPE and LANDINGPAGE variables are missing.

Comment: Can you check this website http://www.theiphoneguyunlocks.com.au/en/tools/solution/iphone-network-finder which has exact codes as mine but somehow it works for credit cards checkout. Mine doesn't.

Comment: That site is passing it over correctly, yours is still not coming over with SOLUTIONTYPE' => 'Sole'  On the last test I ran, it shows Mark is the value that is getting set.

Comment: What do you mean "Mark is the value that is getting set"?

Comment: Do you think this has something to do with my PayPal account or it is a coding error for on my website only?

Comment: At this point it looks like a coding issue, as we are not receiving the correct value for this variable.

Comment: My developer keeps telling me that it is not a coding issue because the other website has the exact code as mine. Do you see or think that these two site may have different codes? What do you think?

Comment: Is the other account yours as well?  If it is, what happens when you replace your credentials with the ones that are used on the other site?  Does it work?  Do you have a sandbox account you can test the code with or a different account?  I ran a test with what your passing over using my account and it is working, and the logs reflect what I am am passing over.  However when looking at the test from your site, it's not showing the variable getting passed over correctly.

Comment: So does this mean it is my PayPal account problem and not website coding problem? You are saying that you used your account on my website and it working fine?

Comment: Hi, does this option have anything to do with my current problem? Accept PayPal payments from all your online stores
Use this feature to automatically accept payments from all your online stores and shopping carts before setting up API permissions.

Accept PayPal payments before API permissions or credentials are set up
(You can complete API setup later)
Block payments from uncredentialed shopping carts
(blocks payments from online stores or shopping carts until you set up API permissions)

Comment: This should not be an account issue, as I checked your account and I did see that you do have the PayPal account optional setting turned on.  I was stating I ran a test with what you say you are passing over and my account credentials and they work.  So the variables are working, it just appears that you are not passing them over when I look at your API call.  Try just creating a string of what you are sending over, and paste it into the browser address bar so that you can see what is getting passed over and than see if on the checkout page you see the option to pay with a credit card

Comment: Hi, How do I create a string to paste into browser address bar? Thx.

Comment: You would just capture the request you are sending, and use it in a string.  It would look like the following example.  https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?USER=test_api1.x.com&PWD=NGTE53SEWP367NDXP2&SIGNATURE=AefiZ4smtdchFhLFKNKS8OSVA0f08NWMEk1J-tsdbDOFq0JpNi&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&VERSION=98.0&RETURNURL=https://paypal.com/index.php/api-s/paypal-nvp/nvp-quick-test&CANCELURL=https://paypal.com/index.php/api-s/paypal-nvp/nvp-quick-test&SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole&LANDINGPAGE=Billing&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=524.20

Comment: Seems like by magic my website now accepts credit cards with PayPal checkout. I don't know how it was fixed. Can you please verify for me please. Thanks.

Comment: I think it is still not fixed as I tried to enter my credit card to checkout and it says "Your account is not verified. Only PayPal verified accounts are allowed to make transactions on our website. Please verify your PayPal account and try again." Why does it say this if I am trying to checkout with my credit card? Seems like customers still need a PayPal account to use their credit cards right?